# Source to the book Théorie des groupes de Lie

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the course of my doctoral studies on Lie algebras and Lie groups, many references are done to the book *Théorie des groupes de Lie* by Claude Chevalley. Can anyone suggest the source to it? The book is in French, are there any english editions of it? Any help is earnestly appreciated.
Editing to add the edition number tome I, Tome II and III (english versions required)

Comment: Have you asked your university librarian?

Comment: [Dover has a cheap English edition](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486824535.html).

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yes I bought the book. But it does not contain the contents of this book.

Comment: Do you mean "[Theory of Lie groups. 1946 Princeton University Press" by Claude Chevalley](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691049908/theory-of-lie-groups-pms-8-volume-8)? it is in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it online there, in French:

https://www.placedeslibraires.fr/ebook/9782402623636-theorie-des-groupes-de-lie-claude-chevalley/

Comment: Thank you for your reference. Are there english versions of the same book?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pdf (in French) at

https://www.eyrolles.com/Sciences/Livre/theorie-des-groupes-de-lie-9782402623636/

Price : $9.99€$

It is for free at

https://ebookstoread.club/sl-SNSZH-D7256/signup-dual/#/z=yzqLaS2VHkX6Yp92aWyzdl/variation=default/q=theorie-des-groupes-de-lie-theoremes-generaux-sur-les-algebres-de-lie.pdf/s1=C6SwdxfviaZAumGNnD7iEf/s2=/s3=/s4=/s5=/source_id=478f429c-36ad-0f5c-c9c3-84713ddc2724/project=g9yQex/mh_offer_id=/dp=zyxbxKflql65awwJjaidR3/m=/c_bg=/c_img1=/c_img2=/c_color=/source=Referral/software=Browser/domain=cdn.bk4ad.club/

Comment: Are there english versions of it? I do not understand French.